# How to split a text-block into 2 strings, with PHP?

Tags: php, string

I have a text-block, with this content:

```
There is my first text.

---

There is my second text, 1.
There is my second text, 2.
...
```

Now, I want to split it into 2 strings:

1. `$str_1 = "There is my first text.";`
2. `$str_2 = "There is my second text, 1.
   There is my second text, 2.";`

How can I split a text-block into 2 strings with PHP?

---

**Note**:
1. `---` can be more, such as: `----`, `-----` ...
2. `There is my first text.` is always the beginning of text-block.

---

Because, my text-structure was changed. So, my question has some mini changes. I am appoligized for this.

Comment: use `explode()` function

Answer (score 1):

[Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is your friend here. Explode the text-block with `[*]` as separator and use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) on it to remove the first empty element.

```
$str = "[*]There is my first text.[*]

There is my second text, 1.
There is my second text, 2.";
$result = array_filter(explode("[*]", $str));
```

after execution you first text will be in `$result[0]` and second text in `$result[1]`

EDIT: after you changed your requirements, use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$str = "There is my first text.

---

There is my second text, 1.
There is my second text, 2.";
print_r(preg_split("/-+/", $str));
```

This will separate the text using any number of `-'s` as a separator

Comment: You get my vote, for using the proper way and harnessing `preg_split()`.

Answer (score -1):

See [php explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Something like so

```
$arr = explode("\n", $str)
```

Will generate an array with the following

```
[0] = [*]There is my first text
[1] = 
[2] = There is my second text, 1
[3] = There is my second text, 2
```